# Accpetp Images to email and process the images

Tags: email

I want to create an email account which will accept image attachments.
download the attachments, process the images with the batch script I have ...
please tell me which email server I should use to do this ( Linux only )
and also please tell me if I can use gmail account to do this ??
thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) to retrieve email messages from a Gmail (POP3/IMAP) account. It does require you have a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) configured for at least local mail delivery. Most Linux distro's do this by default already (eg [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/), [Exim](http://www.exim.org/), etc).

Then you can use [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) or [Maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) to apply filters to the incoming messages and pipe the message to your extracting program(s).

Comment: You can also use `getmail` instead of fetchmail; it will deliver directly to mdir (i.e. directory with one file per mail), or pipe it to a script.